# What is the value of $1+\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{4^4} + \cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the value of this series?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{4^4} + \cdots
$$

I found the answer to be equal to $1.29$ by converting the sum to an integral.

Comment: @BAI, clearly, it's the latter.

Comment: If it's latter, look up [Sophomore's dream](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

Comment: Actually you can get four exact decimal adding the first five terms 
$$1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{256}+\frac{1}{3125}\approx 1.2912$$